# New site accounts are created with old profile information

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

Whenever I try to create accounts for other sites in the Stack Exchange Network, the new accounts display an old profile and username. I don't know how to delete the older data and/ or update that data to display the new profile and username.

Comment: Is "jarnosz" your old username? Try going to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4541690), then click on "Update profile info", and select which site to copy the info from. Also, to save the info to all _existing_ profiles, go to [Edit profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) _here_ and click on "Save and copy changes to all public communities".

Comment: in your [edit profile settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) page  there is a blue button near the bottom that allows you to sync that profile to all other profiles.

Comment: the old username is erreka: keeps popping up every time I try to set up a new account (like in this meta site).

Comment: Do you have that name used in your developer story by any chance?

Comment: It seems to be copying information from your [Area 51 profile](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/163035). No idea why it chooses that one, but it's where your user history says it was copied from when you created the profile.

Comment: _"like in this meta site"_ Then, edit one of the profiles that have the updated username and then click _"Save and copy changes to all public communities"_. You might also need to (manually) edit your Area 51 profile as per animuson's comment.

Comment: @rene I have no clue. How could I check that?

Comment: @anumison How did you figure out that?

Comment: @41686d6564, anumison is right on target. Seems like a bug, then.

Comment: I can't login into [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com). Perhaps it has indeed been abducted by outer space aliens!! O_o

Comment: I would assume checking all fields in your developer story https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/5948996 would reveal that. But given the response from Animuson (SE staff with access to internal and the codebase) I wouldn't bother as the root cause is likely your A51 profile.